# Gutenberg Reusable Block of WordPress

Tags: block-editor

I'm using an custom theme and I would like to take the id to the values ​​of a reusable block. I have this code:

```
<?php
$post = get_post();
if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
   $blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content() ); 
     foreach($blocks as $block) {
        $id= isset($block['attrs']['id']) ? $block['attrs']['id'] : '';
        echo $id;
     }
}
```

I see the id of all blocks but not reusable blocks. how do I access reusable block data?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it worked for me:

```php
$post = get_post( $post_id );

if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
    $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );

    foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
        if ( isset( $block['attrs']['id'] ) ) {
                echo $block['attrs']['id'];
        } elseif ( 'core/block' === $block['blockName'] ) {
            $block_content = parse_blocks( get_post( $block['attrs']['ref'] )->post_content );
            if ( isset( $block_content[0]['attrs']['id'] ) ) {
                echo $block_content[0]['attrs']['id'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```